# Question about linear algebra in Benson's book "Representations theory of elementary abelian groups and vector bundles"

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, field-theory, representation-theory

The following proposition is in Benson's book:

> Proposition 4.1.2 Suppose $k$ is algebraically closed. Let $A_1,A_2\in M_{n\times m}(k)$, regarded as maps from $k^m$ to $k^n$. Then:
>   (1) Suppose that forall $\lambda,\mu\in k$, not both zero, $\lambda A_1+\mu A_2$ is injective. Then $$\bigcap_{(\lambda,\mu)\neq (0,0)}Im(\lambda A_1+\mu A_2)=0$$
>   (2) Suppose that forall $\lambda,\mu\in k$, not both zero, $\lambda A_1+\mu A_2$ is surjective. Then $$\sum_{(\lambda,\mu)\neq (0,0)}Ker(\lambda A_1+\mu A_2)=k^m$$

This is very interesting proposition and the proof in the book is very beautiful. The proof in the book used field extension. I am wondering if this can be proved by methods of linear algebra. Any helps will be appreciated.

The following is proof in the book:
[image]

Th4.1.1 is that the rank is preserved when consider field extension and take algebraic independent variables.

Comment: You have named both statements (1), which I assume is a typo. Second statement can not be true, so I assume there is an error. Intersection of kernels equal to $k^m$ would mean all the maps are zero.

Comment: Sorry, thank you. I corrected it.